# A Joint Density Problem Involving Change of Variable

Tags: probability, integration

A point $(X,Y)$ is picked at random uniformly in the unit circle. 
Find the joint density of $R$ and $X$, where $R^2 = X^2 + Y^2$.

So the question is asking for $f_{R, X} (r, x) = \mathbb P(R=r, X=x)$. 
Now, if I integrate$f_{R, X} (r, x)$ over all values of $r$, I will have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{R, X}(r, x) dr = \mathbb P(R \le {\infty}, X=x) = f_X (x)$$
Of course, I can recover $f_X (x)$ from the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X, Y}(x, y) dy =
\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} {1 \over \pi} dy = {2 \over \pi} \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
The way the problem is set up suggests the following solution:
$$f_{R, X} (r, x) = {d \over dx} \left[ {2 \over \pi} \sqrt{1-x^2} \right]{dx \over dr}$$
However, I am not entirely sure of how to justify the above. 
Let $x$ be a fixed value.  Via the FOTC, I have the following: 
$$f_{R, X} (r, x) = \mathbb P(R=r, X=x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {1 \over h}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{r+h} f_{R, X}(r, x) dr \space - \int_{-\infty}^{r} f_{R, X}(r, x) dr \right]$$
I think I am on the right track.  But after I'm given $f_{X, Y}$, a function of $x$ and $y$, 
I am having a hard time imagining what $f_{R, X}$, a function of $x$ and $r$, looks like. 
Specifically, what is the the region in the $XR$ plane over which $f_{R,X}$ is defined?

Comment: $f_{R, X} (r, x)$ **does not** mean $\mathbb P(R=r, X=x)$ which, incidentally, happens to have value $0$ for all choices of $r$ and $x$ in this problem.

Comment: No wonder something did not seem right.  TY for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density function is defined everywhere. But in effect you are asking where anything interesting is happening. That is the part of the $X$-$R$ plane where $0\le r\le 1$ and $|x|\le r$. This is a triangle, really two triangles glued together. (There is symmetry across the $R$-axis.) The corners are $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(-1,1)$.

To see this, note that we are in the unit disk, so $0\le R\le 1$. And the only restriction on $X$ is that since $X^2+Y^2=R^2$, we have $|X|\le R$. Thus we must be above the "curve" $r=|x|$.

Comment: Really?  I rewrote the expression into $x = \sqrt{r^2-y^2}$, where y is given.  So I got a hyperbolic figure ....

Comment: For any **fixed** $y$, you indeed get (part of) a hyperbola. But $y$ is not fixed, in fact is not (directly) in the game, we are looking for the joint density of $X$ and $R$.